# Lexmark MS621 printer won't give me JobInfoCollection nor PrintQueue statuses

Tags: c#, printing, printqueue

I'm trying to write an app that prints periodically.
I've developed the app and I tested it with my [HP Photosmart B110a](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-photosmart-wireless-e-all-in-one-printer---b110a/4022328/model/4022329) printer and everything works fine, but on this next printer, which is a [Lexmark MS621](http://support.lexmark.com/index?productCode=LEXMARK_MS621&focusedTab=PUBLICATIONS&page=product&userlocale=EN_US#1) I don't get anything back from PrintQueue.
Why is that? Am I missing something?

To boil it down, this is the code that has to work.

```cs
//PDFtoPrinter documentation: https://github.com/svishnevsky/PDFtoPrinter
static void Print()
{
    using (LocalPrintServer printServer = new LocalPrintServer(PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministrateServer))
    {
        using (PrintQueue queue = new PrintQueue(printServer, printServer.DefaultPrintQueue.Name, PrintSystemDesiredAccess.AdministratePrinter))
        {
            //Start printing
            new PDFtoPrinterPrinter().Print(new PrintingOptions(printServer.DefaultPrintQueue.Name, @"C:\Pdf\blank.pdf")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            queue.Refresh(); //Just to make sure I refresh the queue

            if (queue.NumberOfJobs > 1) //On my HP printer this if statement returns true after I started printing, but on the Lexmark it says there is no printjob even tho it started to print!
                Console.WriteLine("There is a job!");

            foreach (PrintSystemJobInfo info in queue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection())  //I've tried to print out all JobInfo on the printer, on the HP I get one, but on Lexmark I get 0
                Console.WriteLine(info.Name);

            PrintSystemJobInfo jobInfo = queue.GetPrintJobInfoCollection().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals("blank.pdf")); //Get the jobInfo of the current file that I'm trying to print. Again, on HP I get the jobInfo but on the Lexmark I get nothing.

            if (queue.IsOutOfPaper)  //When I start to print without the printer having any paper this line on the HP returns true, but on the Lexmark it's alwaysfalse.
                Console.WriteLine("There is no paper!");

            if(jobInfo.IsPaperOut)  //Same problem...
                Console.WriteLine("There is no paper!");
        }
    }
}
```

One additional information.
The HP one is a network printer, the Lexmark one is connected via USB and I printed a test page with both.
Of course the driver is different, but the driver type too!
The Lexmark one is `type 3` while the HP is `type 4`, maybe this has to do something with the way this works?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @KJ Hmmm... that check box is greyed out on the Lexmark!
I'll comment if it's ticked or not on the HP later, when I have the oppurtunity

Comment: @KJ I just checked the HP printer, and it's greyed out there too

Comment: @KJ I just texted them, I'll let you know what did they say asap, thanks! :)